# Why are iframe uploads so slow?

Tags: apache, firefox, iframe, upload, centos

Is there a reason server-side or client-side why uploading even a tiny file via the iframe method can take such a long time?

I'm just trying to upload a file via an iframe so the user doesn't have to leave the page. It all works but it's incredibly slow. Oddly enough, one time in umpteen, it will actually go through quickly. I'm not sure what's going on.

Browser is Firefox 3.6. Server is CentOS 4 with HTTPd 2.0.

Comment: Hi @Dale Forester have you tried the same upload without the iframe? What sort of differences are you observing?

Comment: @Alex Key I haven't. Maybe I'll try that when I get some time. Thanks for the look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, turns out the code I got from elsewhere was submitting using the same form which in this case was very large. It made the browser compile everything for submission just for the upoad. And the server-side process had to decompile all of that on its end, too. Combined, I guess that's why it was slow.

Comment: Glad your startin to get to the bottom of it. As an alternative, maybe try your upload via AJAX rather than an iframe - has the same benifits of not needing to leave the page. There's some good open source upload scripts around such as: http://www.uploadify.com/